# How to write foreach loop for array in php

Tags: php

After submitting the form i am getting the array

```
$regData = {"student":"699","eposter":"99","exhibitor":"1199","Single-2-nights":"400"};
```

I need this look like this:

```
student : 699  
eposter : 99  
exhibitor : 1199  
Single-2-nights : 400
```

I am writing this like:

```
<?php
foreach($regData as $key => $value){  
    $selected .= $key." :". $value."<br/>";  
}  
?>
```

Showing error

```
invalid argument passed to forech
```

Please help me to fix this error

Comment: `$regData` looks more like JSON and as it stands, won't work as an array.  If you had quotes round it, then try `json_decode()`.

Comment: Please provide your debugging attempts, and a full reproducable example. In the given snippet, `$regData` is undefined - where does it come from?

Comment: `$regData = {"student":"699","eposter":"99","exhibitor":"1199","Single-2-nights":"400"};` isn't valid PHP. This can't be your real code. Please clarify. Is it actually a string like `$regData = '{"student":"699","eposter":"99","exhibitor":"1199","Single-2-nights":"400"}';`, perhaps? That would be valid. Then, as the first comment above says, you could decode it into an array / object and then use it easily in a loop.

Comment: Are looking for something like this ? http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0b20ffab91cbfeef3d0366c451fb1b77a329c9e8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a JSON String, You have to decode it first using Json_decode

```
    $regData = '{"student":"699","eposter":"99","exhibitor":"1199","Single-2-nights":"400"}';
    $arrayData = json_decode($regData,true);
    $selected ='';
    foreach($arrayData as $key => $value){
    $selected .= $key." :". $value."<br/>";
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$regData = '{"student":"699","eposter":"99","exhibitor":"1199","Single-2-nights":"400"}';
print_r(json_decode($regData));
```

will result an object

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.
A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Answer (score 1):

```
$regData = ["student" => "699",
            "eposter" => "99",
            "exhibitor" => "1199",
            "Single-2-nights" => "400"];
```

in php, array should be in square brackets

```
foreach($regData as $key => $value){  
    $selected .= $key." :". $value."<br/>";  
}
```

Foreach code is OK.

?>

Comment: In PHP, arrays also use `=>` instead of `:`.

Comment: @executable the OP's data isn't valid PHP, so, no-one can use that. If you see the comments on the main thread, above, you'll note that people are asking OP to clarify if it's actually meant to be a JSON string, or what. But this example here would serve a a valid sample, assuming that the data in the original question then gets decoded to a valid associative array.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Ganesh I Checked your code, your foreach loop syntax is fine but It's a better practice to write `endforeach;` at the end of loop + in your array replace `:` with `=>`

Comment: *but It's a better practice to write endforeach;* - where do you get this idea from?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: That page only mentions `endforeach` once and nothing in there says it's *best practice*